# How to automatically start an android activity and proceed to next activity with many buttons designs

Tags: android

Well i am going to start an "Open Day at University" android application.Actually i was learning some android and java programming some the last 5 months.Now am actually going to start my app.My problem is that i want to have a logo screen(Activity) and then my home screen(Another activity). I want that when I start my application my logo screen should come and then automatically after (say 5 )secs my home screen should appear. Also in my homescreen i want to have some button designs(Since i have many many activities) in which the buttons are to be similar like the one i sent in the link below.Each time i click one one of the buttons it gives me different activities and the process repeat with different buttons.The problem is since i have too many activities,i want my buttons to be small and round similar to the picture.Can some help me how to do this? Help me please am in a really great dilemma.

https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/university-of-sydney-open-day/id1006990948?mt=8

[Homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uXZ4.jpg)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Thread for this purpose.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Thread timer=new Thread(){
    public void run(){
    try{
    sleep(5000);   //freeze app for 5 seconds
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
     e.printStackTrace();

    }finally{


     nextActivity();    // go to next activity


      }}} ;

    timer.start();
    }

   }
   public void nextActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Do not forget to overwrite `onPause()` method

```
    protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();   //finish activity instance so that it is not resumed
   }
```

As for xml just put your logo in a imageView in the `activity_splash.xml`

**EDIT:**

Now for second part of your question:

1. Create a layout 'second_activity.xml' and put buttons there with id say b1,b2,b3 etc
2. Then is your activity do

   ```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1,b2,b3; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b1.setOnclickListener(this);
    b2.setOnclickListener(this);
    b3.setOnclickListener(this);

    }



        @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   switch(v.getId()){

   case R.id.b1:
       Intent go = new Intent(this,anotheractivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);

       break;

   case R.id.b2:
       Intent go = new Intent(this,yetanotheractivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);

       break;  

   case R.id.b3:

       Intent go = new Intent(this,yetyetanotheractivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);


       break;

   }}


   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks zahan its working! :) Now the second part of my question that is the next Homescreen activity which has multiple buttons for various activities. Please find attached link i pasted above: "Homescreen". thank you

Comment: Edited the answer with the second part too. take a look if it helps @user5485022

Comment: any other solution using gridview with button?

Comment: You can also do that. you can also use relative layout that your wish.@user5485022